# Do I need ISP authentication after factory reset of my router?

Tags: networking, router

I have Internet connection with router Technicolor model [TC2700K](https://www.kabeldeutschland.de/csc/hilfe/geraete/wlan_kabelrouter_technicolor)

Since the landlord is abroad, and he don’t remember the password to access the admin panel, do I need the internet contract after the factory reset of the router?

I remember that I lost connection with another model Thomson TG585 and I needed the ISP contract to provide

ISP credential in admin panel, but now I don’t have any information.

---

Comment: It depends whether the ISP preconfigured the modem/router to connect to the Internet (the initial dial-up username/password). Most of the time you can reset the modem/router using the pin-hole button on the device. This should at least reset the router to whatever the initial configuration. Be careful, though, if the modem needs to be setup by entering a username and password to dial in (and you don't have these) then you'll need to phone the ISP and have the account holder's permission.

Comment: ...so: you'll have to contact the ISP, or find info on their website.

Comment: I checked the [User manual](https://www.kabeldeutschland.de/psources/media/Bedienungsanleitung%20TC7200K%2009-2013.pdf) and some screens (in German) and I didn't find a special screen for ISP information, can you confirm please? I don't speak German and I cannot phone the company :(
For DHCP, DNS, Wlan setup etc.. this is not an issue, because I can configure them correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I read in Internet DSL Router use a Phone Line and need username/password provided by ISP to connect to WAN using PPPoE/PPPoA protocol, but for Cable Router (using coaxial cable) they don't need access credential to access the Internet.

I did the reset correctly and modified the default Wifi Channel, SSID, Wifi key and the default Admin password and now I'm posting using it :)

Answer (score 1):

The general answer is: you have to have all details about how to connect to your ISP.

*... and this will of course depend on their setup entirely.*

This MAY be as simple as just connecting the cables correctly - assuming:

- DHCP in use at your ISP,
- DHCP client (towards ISP/WAN) in the router and
- DHCP server (towards the LAN) in the router, and
- DHCP setup in your computer(s)

DHCP = "Receive an IP automatically" in Windows terms.

Comment: I added a comment for my question to explain more the issue, any idea? :)

Comment: Not really, I suspect it is ISP-specific then.

Comment: Yes it is, it has only a german manual and the trailing K in the model name seems related to Kabel Deutschland did you taked a look to the manual? It seems no specific page for the ISP authentification.